# How run a visual studio debug of a uwp proj from powershell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, cmd, uwp, msbuild

I want to run a visual studio uwp proj in debug mode from powershell
I know how to launch my uwp app from external command

> start shell:AppsFolder\packageName arguments

But what I want to do this from visual studio like in debug mode. 
Do you know how to do this please?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Do you want to run the UWP with a debugger attached? (so you can catch crashes, etc.?)

Comment: I want to click on the debug icone of an opened visual studio but if it is not possible yes I want to want to run the UWP with a debugger attached

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. You can mark it as answer, which can be beneficial to other community members. It can be easier for them to search the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From sln folder

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7`\IDE\devenv.exe"  /command "Debug.Start" my_solution.sln
```